# How do I get the dom node of a child element in a component without adding logic to its parent/children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following example `WrapperComp` needs to get access to the dom node of the `divs` in line 5 and line 8, without adding logic to `PageComp` or `ItemComp`. The only things I could change in `PageComp` are the div tags. E.g. I could add a `ref`, `prop`, `data-attribute`, etc to them.

The `divs` don't have to be created inside `PageComp`. `WrapperComp` would be allowed to create them too, but they must wrap each of its children (In this case each `ItemComp`).

**Example**

```
class PageComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <WrapperComp>
      <div>
        <ItemComp/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ItemComp/>
      </div>
    </WrapperComp>
    );
  }
}

class WrapperComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>A wrapper</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ItemComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>An item</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PageComp/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cibiferexe/edit?html,js,console,output)

What I tried so far:

- I already tried to put a `ref=` on the `divs`, but that `ref` would only be available in `PageComp` not in `WrapperComp`.
- I also tried to create the `divs` inside `WrapperComp` and put a `ref=` on them  from there, but that would result in a [Refs Must Have Owner Warning](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html)

Now I wonder.. what would be an appropriate way in react to solve that problem?

Till now the only solution that came to my mind was to put a `data-attribute` on each `div` and search the dom for them after `componentDidMount` like that: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-xxx]')`. Perhaps I'm not sure if this is how you do it in react..

Why do I want to get the node inside `WrapperComp`?

I want to create a component that adjusts the dimensions of its children. In the example that component would be `WrapperComp`. The adjustments can only be done after the children rendered to the dom, e.g. to get `clientHeight`.

Comment: we can access the refs using `this.props.children.ref` in your WrapperComponent.

Comment: Could you please show me an example on how that works? I couldn't figure out a way to get a dom node from `this.props.children.ref` inside `WrapperComp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't restrict that this needs to be solved by how one should get the DOM, pass them down, etc, I would get rid of the puzzle and approach it in a different direction.

Since you are not given much control to `<PageComp>` whereas `<WrapperComp>` seems flexible, I would do the wrapping in the later by transforming the passed children to what you need them to be.

```
class PageComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WrapperComp>
        <ItemComp/>
        <ItemComp/>
      </WrapperComp>
    );
  }
}

class WrapperComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const wrappedChldren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
      return (
        <div ref={function(div) {
            this.setState{clientHeight: div.clientHeight}
        }}>
          <h1>A wrapper</h1>
          { child }
        </div>
      ); 
    });
    return <div>{ wrappedChildren }</div>;
  }
}
```

With this concentrate can be put on the transformation in the `<WrapperComp>`, which is pretty intuitive as its name suggests.

Comment: `I also tried to create the divs inside WrapperComp`. But how would you get the `clientHeight` of each `div` so that you can use it inside `WrapperComp` in your example? You need to render the `divs` before you can use `clientHeight`.

Comment: If a `ref` callback is added to the wrapper, `<div ref={function(div) {console.log(div.clientHeight)}}>`, the height of the wrapper will be fetched  when it becomes available. It is essentially what @Galeel Bhasha suggested, but a different technique to derive a reference to the wrapper. If this is what you ask for, I gotta amend my answer to target at it.

Comment: It seems to work now. It's strange, because when I tried it last time I got the *"Refs Must Have Owner Warning"*. Anyways... this really looks like the appropriate way to do it in react. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Rotareti, It shall be dependent on how `ref` was added. Well I am glad to help a bit.